# What is the right way to Computing correct predictions in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm feeding a simple ConvNet in Tensorflow using a tfrecords file containing grayscale images as inputs and integer class labels.

my loss is defined as `loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_conv, label_batch)`

where `y_conv=tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop,W_fc2) + b_fc2`

and `label_batch` is tensor of size `[batch_size]`.

I'm trying to compute the accuracy by using

```
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(label_batch,1),tf.argmax(y_conv, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
```

This `correct_prediction` statement is giving an error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Minimum tensor rank: 2 but got: 1
```

I'm a bit confused as to how exactly one computes correct predictions in TF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your `y_conv` you do everything right -- it is a matrix of shape `(batch_size, n_classes)` where for each sample and for each class you have a probability that this is the class the image belongs to. So to get the actual predicted class you need to call `argmax`.

However your labels are integers and have a shape of just `(batch_size,)`, because the class of an image is known and there's no reason to supply `n_classes` probabilities, a single integer can hold the actual class just as well. So you don't need to call `argmax` on it to convert probabilities to a class, it already has the class. To fix it, just do

```
correct_prediction = tf.equal(label_batch, tf.argmax(y_conv, 1))
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use 0 for the dimension argument to tf.argmax since label_batch and y_conv are vectors.  Using dimension=1 implies a tensor rank of at least 2.  See the documentation for the dimension parameter of argmax [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#argmax).

I hope that helps!

Comment: The first dimension is samples. The dimension=1 is the correct dimension when you compute accuracy.